# I m getting 3types of errors1) RenderBox was not laid out2) Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize' and Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, render

I am creating a todo app that contains TaskList and Task Tiles and by creating check boxes of task lists and using call back functions I got 3 types of errors.

1. RenderBox was not laid out 2) Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize' 3)Null check operator used on a null value

TaskList class code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoey_flutter/widgets/TaskTile.dart';


class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        TaskTile(),
        TaskTile(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

TaskTile code that contains checkbox and callback:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}


class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  bool isChecked= false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'This is my task.',
        style: TextStyle(
        decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
    ),),
      trailing: TaskCheckBox(isChecked, (bool checkboxState) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = checkboxState;
        });
      },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {

  TaskCheckBox (this.checkboxState, this.toggleCheckBoxState);
  final bool checkboxState;
  final Function toggleCheckBoxState;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: checkboxState,
        onChanged: toggleCheckBoxState(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: fixe 1-> onChanged: ()=>toggleCheckBoxState(),

Comment: please check the answer i hope it's working for you

Comment: It didn't worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's solved your solution

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
 children: <Widget>[
        TaskTile(),
        TaskTile(),
      ],
)
```

TaskTile class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}


class _TaskTileState extends State<TaskTile> {
  bool isChecked= false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        'This is my task.',
        style: TextStyle(
          decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
        ),),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (value){
          setState(() {
            isChecked = value;
          });
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wait a moment i will check again

Comment: updated my answer, TaskCheckBox don't need just implement this in trailing because in trailing you don't update setState value without checkBox

Comment: No, the moment I assigned **value** to the **isChecked** it popped up with the following error : A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.

Comment: It worked just added ! at the end of a value. Thank you very much.

Comment: it's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

fixe 1-> `onChanged: ()=>toggleCheckBoxState()`
and 2nd May be decoration cant be null, so pass TextDecoration(), empty constructor.

and 3rds If listview has constraint parent then, wrap listview with `Expanded` or `shrinkWrap` true.

Comment: There isn't any boxDecoration in the given code. Were you talking about the text Decoration.